# How to reroute browser to a custom "User Not In Role" page when MSAL fails acquiring a token in Angular 6

Tags: azure, angular6, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to implement Implicit flow using Angular 6/MSAL. The client is trying to get an ID token from Azure AD. Our AD Client is configured to provide tokens only for certain users and groups. So, when an unauthorized user (still a user inside the organization) tries to login, Azure Ad directly reroutes them to the Login Page, which is not very intuitive. I would like to redirect them to a custom page, indicating that the user is not in any of the roles required by the application.

But MSAL has no option for something like "failedRedirectUri". Can someone please tell me if this is even possible with MSAL, if so how do i go about configuring it?

I've tried to set the "redirectUri" from localStorage, and try to modify it before the redirect happens. but that doesn't help.

```
MsalModule.forRoot({
      clientID: '*****-************************',
      authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/*************************/",
      validateAuthority: true,
      redirectUri: window.location.origin,
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
      postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin + "/loggedout",
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
      popUp: false,
      unprotectedResources: ["https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/"],
      protectedResourceMap: protectedResourceMap,
      logger: loggerCallback,
      correlationId: "1000",
      level: LogLevel.Info,
      piiLoggingEnabled: true
  })
```

On login failure for implicit flow, the user should not be redirect to the "redirectUrl" page. Instead the user should be taken to an error page where the error description is displayed.

Comment: Please take a look at Zamzowd comment here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/585.  One strategy is you create a separate redirecturi.html page.  It just has the msal library and basic logic that redirect back to your application page.  This approach has worked for me.  You can check for `params.error` and redirect back to the appropriate page in your app. Not sure if `msal:notAuthorized` or `msal:errorResponse` or `msal:loginFailure` will help.